# change active selection from list in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one little problem, I included submenu on this page: http://www.shadowopsweaponry.com/default.aspx.

On the left side there is 'gunsmithing' category and if you click on that link a new submenu pops up below that link.

Also there are two other submenus 'gun coating' and 'firearm training' which are acting same, even if you click on other main link after that, they are staying highlighted. 
When I am clicking on some of the submenu links I want that selection to be highlighted and not the one which I selected before that, how can I achieve that?

**Edit:** Adding CSS.

```
.arrowsidemenu {
    width: 180px; /*width of menu*/
    background: #212121;
}

.menucontents div.selected a { /*header that's currently selected*/
    color: #f93;
}

.arrowsidemenu .menuheaders a { }

.arrowsidemenu div a { /*header bar links*/
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.arrowsidemenu div a:link, .arrowsidemenu div a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

.arrowsidemenu div a:hover { }

.arrowsidemenu div.unselected a { /*header that's currently not selected*/
    color: #fff;
}

.arrowsidemenu div.selected a { /*header that's currently selected*/
    color: #f93;
}

.arrowsidemenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.arrowsidemenu ul li {
    line-height: 8px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.arrowsidemenu ul li a { /*sub menu links*/
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.arrowsidemenu ul li a:hover { }

.active-sub-menu {
    color: #f93;
}
```

Comment: It's helpful to post some code also.

Comment: I'd suggest it's ***essential*** to post the relevant code, otherwise, once the problem's fixed the question becomes entirely useless (since the problem page no longer exists in its problematic form). Please reduce the code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) form and, if you're able, consider posting a live demo that we can work with (at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Your class called "selected" is being placed onto div > a href.  You need that class instead to land on ul > li> a href.  This is a problem in your .aspx, not really in the css.

If you get the html fixed, you'll want to change this line:

```
.arrowsidemenu div.selected a {
  color: #FF9933;
 }
```

At that point, probably you can just use .selected instead.

You can see these more easily by using Firebug, addon for Firefox.  If you get it, you can right-click an item to see what styles are applied.